# TypeError: redirect() got an unexpected keyword argument 'logout'

Tags: python, flask

Prevents me from passing along the boolean `logout` to index.  I used the exact same `redirect` format in another part of code, which worked.

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
  error = None
  if request.method == 'POST':
    if request.form['username'] != 'user' or \
    request.form['password'] != 'pass':
      error = 'Invalid credentials'
    else:
      session['username'] = request.form['username']
      flash('You are already logged in.')
      logout = False
      return redirect(url_for('index'), logout=logout) #problem line
  return render_template('login.html', error=error)
```

Comment: This doesn't make sense. You're passing a boolean (False) to `redirect`. Why, and what are you expecting that to do?

Comment: Look at the [source code of `redirect`](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/werkzeug/blob/master/werkzeug/utils.py#L338) - it doesn't accept a `logout` keyword argument (and probably never has). That "other part of code" where you used the `logout` keyword argument probably only "worked" because that line was never executed.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to pass the `logout` value to `url_for()`:

```
redirect(url_for('index', logout=logout))
```

However, in this case it'd be a good idea to convert it to int first - otherwise you end up with a literal `False` or `True` in the URL.

Comment: I doubt that's because of my diamond. But if I saw our two answers without autorship information I'd upvote mine because it's more likely (passing a boolean to `code` makes zero sense).